# What might block the creation of thumbnails?

Tags: 8, media

My Drupal 8 does not create thumbnail. I have set my files folder's permission to 775 and the folder 2016-10 is not there.

> [image]

There is no error shown in the log, and the temporary directory is /tmp.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to look for this file: /var/www/httpd-logs/your_site.com.error.log

So, edit your sites/default/files/.htaccess

```
# Turn off all options we don't need.
#Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews
Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your php error log, it may show you where the problem come from.

Probably it is related to the settings of temporary directory in configuration > media > file system. It can happen if you have no write permission on temporary directory.